# Mongorestore taking a time to restore collection

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I'm trying to restore the complete DB dump using mongo restore, but there is one collection which is around 70Gb where `mongorestore` is restoring it extremely slow with 10mb/min rate. My server configuration is 2cpu & 7Gb RAM. The server resource utilization is normal when I check with top command.

What could be the reason behind this or this is known issue with mongo restore?

Appreciate any help here

Comment: What is the storage engine your mongodb uses? If wiredtiger, what is the wiredtigercachesize?

Comment: storage engine is 

{"name" : "wiredTiger"}

Here are some details about cache

  "bytes belonging to page images in the cache" : 11707302981,
  "bytes currently in the cache" : 12219492482,
  "bytes not belonging to page images in the cache" : 512189501,
  "bytes read into cache" : NumberLong("2429355268606"),
  "bytes written from cache" : NumberLong("2604746212845"),
  "checkpoint blocked page eviction" : 139667,

Most probably it should be the half of RAM.

Comment: First sorry for few more questions. How many collections do you have in your database, how big they are? How many indexes are defined in all the collections, how big they are? Are you using `--numParallelCollections` or `--numInsertionWorkersPerCollection` aruments when restoring? Are you running any memory consuming operations in parallel to the mongorestore?  Try just restoring the 70GB collection .